# Navigate to parent directory

Tags: c#, ftp

My app is logging into a server, and the default directory based on the user credentials puts it at /dir1/dir2/dir3/.

So there's no problem putting or getting files in dir3, but how do I change directory to dir2 - the parent?

Comment: Ok, to clarify I'm using FtpWebRequest and specifying the file I'd like to get or push. The problem is to get something a directory above, I'm having difficulty. Is there something else I should be using.

Comment: Have you tried using `..` in your URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your path, use %2f instead of ../
For example instead of

```
FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp.com/../parent") as FtpWebRequest
```

do this

```
FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp.com/%2fparent") as FtpWebRequest
```

Comment: Not, but I haven't given it justice w/enough tests.

Comment: BTW, writing `FtpWebRequest.Create()` is confusing, because it's just another way to write `WebRequest.Create()`. `FtpWebRequest` doesn't have a `Create()` method, `WebRequest` does.

Comment: It's good. It puts me all the way into root, but I can give the full path.  Thanks.